# Open of object 'IXMLHTTPRequest' fails inside loop

Tags: excel, vba, msxml

I would like to check my server for the existence of a file every second for about ten seconds. If the file is there, download it. It it is not there (404) try again until, up to a maximum of ten times spread out over ten seconds. I don't usually code in VBA, but here goes.. I have my download function:

```
Function DownloadFile(url As String, fileID As String)

    ' Setup our path where we will save the downloaded file.
    Dim fileSavePath As String
    fileSavePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "-123-" & fileID & ".xlsx"

    ' Use Microsoft.XMLHTTP in order to setup a connection.
    ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(v=vs.85).aspx#methods
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    ' Pass GET to the Open method in order to start the download of the file.
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", url, False ' method, http verb, async = false

    ' Send our request: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536736(v=vs.85).aspx
    WinHttpReq.send

    ' Reset the url parameter to be the body of the response.
    url = WinHttpReq.responseBody

    ' WinHttpReq.Status holds the HTTP response code.
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        ' Setup an object to hold the binary stream of data (the file).
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        ' Set type read only or not: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681553(v=vs.85).aspx
        oStream.Type = 1
        ' Write the binary data to WinHttpReq.responseBody
        ' We can do this because we have confirmed a download via the response code (200).
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile fileSavePath, 2 ' 2 = overwrites the existing file, 1 = will not.
        ' We are done we the stream, close it.
        oStream.Close
        Debug.Print "File downloaded! File path: " & fileSavePath
        DownloadFile = 1
    End If

    ' Handle if the file doesn't exist.
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 404 Then
        DownloadFile = 0
    End If

End Function
```

And I have a Sub which calls this function up to ten times:

```
Sub Callee(url As String, fileID As String)

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

    Do While i < 10

        If DownloadFile(url, fileID) = 1 Then
            Debug.Print "here"
            i = 100
        Else
            Debug.Print fileID & " not found! Try number: " & i
            i = i + 1
            ' We didnt get the response we wanted, so we will wait one second and try again.
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

My code runs only once when I receive a 404 response. When the code tries to loop again I get:

[image: Method open of object IXMLHTTPReuest failed]

I don't understand why my code runs only once, just one time through the loop. I tried to `Set WinHttpReq = Nothing` at the end of my function just in case some sort of garbage collection was not being taken care of, however I realize that this variable is scoped to my function, so...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but this question and answers are misleading.  The code has a bug in the line

```
' Reset the url parameter to be the body of the response.
url = WinHttpReq.responseBody
```

where `url` gets filled with binary data.  Why are you doing this?  Sure using `ByVal` means you get a fresh copy of `url` each time but why are you doing this?  I commented out this line and the problem goes away.

So, IMHO, this has nothing to do with instantiation of `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` and garbage collection its just the `url` passed in was invalid.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I haven't typed a lot of strictly typed languages before and that line is a mistake. I think when I typed that, I had an idea to do something with the ```WinHttpReq.responseBody``` and resetting ```url`` to something else made sense at the time but I guess it can't be a variable of another type. Thank you for pointing that out! At least I know that there was nothing (else) wrong with my code. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to create the `WinHttpReq` in the `Callee` method and just use this object to send the request? Example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Callee(url As String, fileID As String)

    ' Setup our path where we will save the downloaded file.
    Dim fileSavePath As String
    fileSavePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "-123-" & fileID & ".xlsx"

    ' Use Microsoft.XMLHTTP in order to setup a connection.
    ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(v=vs.85).aspx#methods
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    ' Pass GET to the Open method in order to start the download of the file.
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", url, False ' method, http verb, async = false

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

    Do While i < 10

        If DownloadFile(url, fileID, fileSavePath, WinHttpReq) = 1 Then
            Debug.Print "here"
            Exit Do
        Else
            Debug.Print fileID & " not found! Try number: " & i
            i = i + 1
            ' We didnt get the response we wanted, so we will wait one second and try again.
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        End If

    Loop

End Sub

Function DownloadFile(url As String, fileID As String, fileSavePath As String, WinHttpReq As Object)
    ' Send our request: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536736(v=vs.85).aspx
    WinHttpReq.send

    ' Reset the url parameter to be the body of the response.
    url = WinHttpReq.responseBody

    ' WinHttpReq.Status holds the HTTP response code.
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        ' Setup an object to hold the binary stream of data (the file).
        Dim oStream
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        ' Set type read only or not: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681553(v=vs.85).aspx
        oStream.Type = 1
        ' Write the binary data to WinHttpReq.responseBody
        ' We can do this because we have confirmed a download via the response code (200).
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile fileSavePath, 2 ' 2 = overwrites the existing file, 1 = will not.
        ' We are done we the stream, close it.
        oStream.Close
        Debug.Print "File downloaded! File path: " & fileSavePath
        DownloadFile = 1
    End If

    ' Handle if the file doesn't exist.
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 404 Then
        DownloadFile = 0
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Hmm.. Interesting! I didn't think about passing the XMLHTTP method around like that. Unfortunately, I get ```User defined type not defined``` when I try your code this way. Can we pass a method this way in VBA?

Comment: I think I got it sorted! I don't code enough in VBA to know this, but I need to be passing my params to ```DownloadFile``` with the ```ByVal``` keyword like so ```Function DownloadFile(ByVal url As String, ByVal fileId As String)``` Found the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263527(v=vs.60).aspx Admittedly, I'm a little embarrassed but still don't understand why this behavior happened or why the loop would loop only once.

Comment: See the edited answer. The parameter should be of type `Object` because you are using [Late Binding](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation). Why this behaviour happend: you called `open` first and then called `send` which worked fine. But then you called `open` again which failed because `open` was called already. I guess that calling `open` more then once will not work. Therefore the proposal: call `open` once and then just `send` many times and process the result. HTH

Comment: I like the direction you are headed and I too think it's better to instaniate the download object only once and pass it to the download function. However, copy/pasting your code into Excel gives me an "unspecified error" and when I click Debug the debugger breaks on the ```WinHttpReq.send``` line in the ```DownloadFile``` function which leads me to believe that it doesn't have a correct(?) reference to the ```WinHttpReq``` object.